# Refer to ViewModels and Views which are in separate Portable Class Library project

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

Is it possible to refer to Viewmodels which are in a separate portable class library and Views which are in a different portable class library?

My project structure is as follows:

- SampleApp (Portable) -> Views -> SecondPage.xaml
- SampleApp(Droid)
- TestVM (Class Library Project) -> ViewModels -> SecondPageViewModel

In App.cs, I registered the page as follows
`Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<SecondPage, TestVM.ViewModels.SecondPageViewModel>();`

It navigated to SecondPage but the constructor, INavigationAware interface methods didnt get called and mvvm bindings didnt work.

So then I wanted to try solution as explained here [Getting Started with Prism’s new ViewModelLocator](http://brianlagunas.com/getting-started-prisms-new-viewmodellocator/)

I have overridden `ConfigureViewModelLocator`

```
 protected override void ConfigureViewModelLocator()
    {
        base.ConfigureViewModelLocator();
        ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewTypeToViewModelTypeResolver((viewType) =>
        {
            var viewName = viewType.FullName;
            var viewAssemblyName = viewType.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName;
            var viewModelName = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}ViewModel, {1}", viewName, viewAssemblyName);
            return Type.GetType(viewModelName);
        });
    }
```

But how do I refer to the assembly where my viewmodels are located?

Comment: When trying to fetch the view model type, what is `viewName`, `viewAssemblyName` and `viewModelName`? What's the full name of your view model assembly?

Comment: @Haukinger 
**viewName** : SampleApp.Views.SecondPage,

**viewAssemblyName** : SampleApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null,

**viewModelName**: SampleApp.Views.SecondPageViewModel, SampleApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Comment: @Haukinger My view model is located in TestVM class library project, assembly name "TestVM"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can of course override the default configuration for the ViewModel Location Provider. A simpler and faster method however is to use the View/ViewModel registration extension. Just like you can do:

`Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<ViewA>()`

you can also do:

`Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<ViewA,ViewAViewModel>()`

The second method removes the need to locate the ViewModel through reflection which can provide slightly better performance. Because you're providing the ViewModel you do not need to worry about what assembly the ViewModel is in, or if you're following the proper conventions.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment:

> viewModelName: SampleApp.Views.SecondPageViewModel, SampleApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

adapt `var viewModelName = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}ViewModel, {1}", viewName, viewAssemblyName);` so that it produces your *actual* view model name:

```
TestVM.ViewModels.SecondPageViewModel, TestVM, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

Something along the lines of

```
var viewModelName = $"{viewName.Replace("SampleApp","TestVM")}ViewModel, {viewAssemblyName.Replace("SampleApp","TestVM").Replace("Views","ViewModels")}";
```